# element comparison using list comprehension and conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, list-comprehension

I have two lists in the form:

```
a = [[x1, 1], [x2, 0], [x3, 4], [x4, 12], [x5, 15]]

b = [[x2, 10], [x3, 41], [x7, 50]]
```

I thought I could do something like below to get the ids x1, x2, x3 and so on..

```
x = [item for item in b if item in a]

print(x)
[[x2, 10], [x3, 41]]
```

I actually want to print the elements in b that are in a and compare their values

```
[x2, 10] -> [x2, 0]
[x3, 41] -> [x3, 4]
```

so in the example above only print elements from a if `b[0][1] == 0 & a[1][1] != 0`

Any help would be most appreciated!

Comment: what's the sense of that condition `b[0][1] == 0 & a[1][1] != 0` ?

Comment: Where `x2` in both lists, compare the values associated with `x2`

Comment: Is there any reason why you are trying to do this with list comprehensions? A ``for`` loop is significantly easier for complex criteria.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi you are correct, for loop worked out easier. I am new to Python so though I could use list comprehension to find values from a in b!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use:

```
a = [['x1', 1], ['x2', 0], ['x3', 4], ['x4', 12], ['x5', 15]]

b = [['x2', 10], ['x3', 41], ['x7', 50]]

a_dict = dict(a)

print('    b           a')
for x, val in b:
    if x in a_dict:
        print(f'[{x}, {val}] --> [{x}, {a_dict[x]}]')
```

output:

```
    b           a
[x2, 10] --> [x2, 0]
[x3, 41] --> [x3, 4]
```

Comment: Best solution to my problem, thanks! I was able to add two more if statements with the conditions I wanted! Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might be what you are looking for:

```
ax = [item[0] for item in a]
x = [item for item in b if item[0] in ax]
print x
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `list comprehension` with [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)

**Ex.**

```
a = [['x1', 1], ['x2', 0], ['x3', 4], ['x4', 12], ['x5', 15]]
b = [['x2', 10], ['x3', 41], ['x7', 50]]
x = [a[index] for y in b for index,x in enumerate(a) if y[0] == x[0]]
print(x)
```

**O/P:**

```
[['x2', 0], ['x3', 4]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert `a` to a dictionary:

```
adict = dict(a)
```

and then we can just perform a mapping:

```
[[k, adict[k]] for k, __ in b if k in adict]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also make use of python's [operator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) module.

```
import operator

getter = operator.itemgetter(0)
c = [j for i in b for j in a if getter(i) == getter(j)]

print(c)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [['x1', 1], ['x2', 0], ['x3', 4], ['x4', 12], ['x5', 15], ['x7', 60]]

b = [['x2', 10], ['x3', 41], ['x7', 50]]

for x in b:
    if x[0] in dict(a):
        v = dict(a)[x[0]]
        if x[1] > v:
            print('{} -> {}'.format(x, [x[0], v] ))
        else:
            print('{} -> {}'.format([x[0], v] , x))
```

Output

```
['x2', 10] -> ['x2', 0]
['x3', 41] -> ['x3', 4]
['x7', 60] -> ['x7', 50]
```